# How to write Junit for Testing a webservice

Tags: list, jax-rs, junit4, resteasy

I have a RestEasy webservice which calls the methods in a dao class. So i tested the daos seperatley and thats fine. But i did not get how do we test a webservice. My webservice returns response in JSON format. I just wanted to know, in how many scenarios  can we test a webservice. The webservice returns a list as output which is converted to Json response.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test approach is using curl. Otherwise you need to simulate a webclient. I don't know how resteasy does this. In Jersey it is part of the package. You can also use an external test tool like httpunit, htmlunit or selenium.